# How to export image on google earth engine for large area?

Tags: export, ndvi, landsat-8, google-earth-engine

The area that i have been work have about 159695,938 km² and I am mapping the deforestion on this with NDVI. I had to use 2 years to remove all the clouds (eg. 2015-01-31 , 2016-12-31) using a reducer.mean and cfmask band (surface reflatance Landsat 8 image), and when i export.to.drive i got the images separated. Is it possible to join this mean NDVI image in a single image to export? I will use this image in a geoprocessing software.

Comment: as far as I know this is normal and has no solution, but you should ask in the GEE forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers) because some big players answer there, like Gorelick.

Comment: If you are exporting it anyway why not mosaic them afterwards, i.e. with `gdal_merge`?